# How to put a code block inside a String and use it in switch (position)

Tags: java, android, string, listview, web

I have the following code in my app that defines what happens when I click on an item in ListView:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    switch (position) {

    }
}
```

I have a String called data that contains some cases:

```
String data = "case 0:\nLog.i('switchcase','case0');\nreturn;\ncase 1:\nLog.i('switchcase','case1');\nreturn;\ndefault:\nreturn;"
```

My app receives data from The Internet and stores it in the String...

How can I use the code inside the String so that my switch (position) can use the cases in the String?

Comment: While it is possible to construct and compile a class on the fly I do not recommend that. It would open up something like a cross site scripting vulnerability in the app.

Comment: The code in the cases may be any arbitrary java code, or just return a simple string? If the second is the case you can parse it yourself easily by splitting the string, else you must run it on the fly which is dangerous.

Comment: desc = "Test";
owner = "Test";
s1 = "http://www.test.com/test.png";
s2 = "http://www.test.com/test.png";

This Is What A Case Contains In My Application..It Contains Some More Strings And The Strings Are Passed From One Activity To Another Using A Bundle...

Comment: Is There Any Better Way I Can Load The Cases From A Web Server?

Answer (score 0):

There are three answers to this questions.

The first is "NO". This is how viruses start. You do not run code that is injected from an outside source. Java is specifically designed to prevent this kind of hijinks entirely.

The second answer is that you can set up state machine in your code. One where you keep a really large switch statement with all of the possible cases options that you might expect all coded in place. Your incoming data string can then be parsed to decided which one of these cases/states to setup and run. If you have a limited set of options, this is not a big deal. But the more possibilities you offer the bigger your class will get and the harder it will be to maintain. Back in my "procedural" programming days it wasn't uncommon to work on a module with more then 50,000 lines of code.

The last answer is "Reflection". Reflection is the process of inspecting and using the contents of a class without knowing anything about it. Java passes compiled classes from one app to another. As long as the class fits a known interface, and as long as sending and receiving classes have a matched set of security key,s then the receiving class should be able to run the code given to it.

Here is a link that explains the topic in detail:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html

And of course you can searches here at StackOverflow for hints and how to's on reflection.